# What do I do/add to make the bus to stop taking in passengers at 25?

Tags: c#

```
 public void Run()
{
    int menu = 0;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the bus!");
        Console.WriteLine("Choose and option:");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Add passenger");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Check the age of all the passengers on board");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Calculate the total age of all the passengers on board");
        
        
        
        Console.WriteLine("4. Exit the program!");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
        menu = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (menu)
        {
            case 1:
                add_passenger();
                break;

            case 2:
                print_buss();
                break;

            case 3:
                total_age();
                break;

            

        }
    } while (menu != 4);
}

public void add_passenger()
{
    Console.WriteLine("How many passenger do you wanna add?");
    int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write the age of the passenger you wanna add: ");
        int pass = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        passenger[i] = pass;
    }
}

public void print_buss()
{
    Console.WriteLine("The ages of the passengers on the bus are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < passenger.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(passenger[i] + "years old");
    }
}


public int total_age()
{
    int sum = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < passenger.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += passenger[i];
    }
    int total = sum;
    Console.WriteLine("Total age of the passengers on board are " + total);
    return total;
}


}
```

I have a little school project over the summer and this is a little part of code/program im doing and now im stuck. What do I do/add to make the bus to stop taking in passengers at 25? And have it written out that it is full? I have a array for 25, but I dont know what to do to make it stop taking in more people after 25? My head just stands still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your user can call your add_passenger routine multiple times, you need to keep track of how many passengers are on the bus already, and make your add_passenger method refuse to add more than the capacity of the passengers array, knowing how many are there already:

```
public void add_passenger()
{
    Console.WriteLine("How many passenger do you wanna add?");
    int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    //we could do something funky here like checking the request vs the bus size
    if(size > passengers.Length - COUNT_OF_PASSENGERS_ALREADY_ON_THE_BUS)
    {
      //message the user to say that only passengers.Length - COUNT_OF_PASSENGERS_ALREADY_ON_THE_BUS will be added ...
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < size &&  COUNT_OF_PASSENGERS_ALREADY_ON_THE_BUS < passengers.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write the age of the passenger you wanna add: ");
        int pass = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        passenger[COUNT_OF_PASSENGERS_ALREADY_ON_THE_BUS] = pass;
        COUNT_OF_PASSENGERS_ALREADY_ON_THE_BUS++;
    }
}
```

COUNT_OF_PASSENGERS_ALREADY_ON_THE_BUS is an integer, declared in the same place as the `passengers` array (and give it a nicer name than COUNT_OF_PASSENGERS_ALREADY_ON_THE_BUS - I only used all caps to make it clear the places in the code I used it)

You'll need to know how many passengers are on the bus so you can process other operations. It doesn't matter so much for the "add up the ages" thing because the slots you didn't use yet are pre filled with zeroes, so they wouldn't contribute to a sum, but if the task were switched to eg calculate the average age, then you'd have a problem

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OP said in the question "i have an array for 25" which I took to mean passenger.Length already is 25, and because arrays don't change length, this will always be the case

Comment: Sorry posted the commen to your answer, was supposed to post to the question instead.

Answer (score -1):

While I do not see where you created the`passenger` array, I see that you have used it multiple times in your code. Also, you should convert it to a `List` to make it really work. So, you can simply add an `if` statement to your `add_passenger` method:

```
List<int> passenger = new List<int>();
  public void add_passenger()
{
if(passenger.Length != 25){ //checking if the amount of passengers is not already equal to 25
    Console.WriteLine("How many passenger do you wanna add?");
    int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if(passenger.Length+size < 26) //checking if the request does not exceed the passenger capacity
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write the age of the passenger you wanna add: ");
        int pass = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        passenger.Add(pass);
    }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Do not introduce too much new code (like `List<int>`) on questions that are clearly programming 101 assignments. Nothing screams "I copied this off the internet" more than using e.g. a collection class that hasn't even been taught yet. For people in the OP's position the objective is to teach them to better understand what they should already know, rather than demonstrate the awesome power of advanced C#

Comment: @CaiusJard Instead of introducing a new variable like you did in you answer, you can simple turn the array into a `List` like I did, and check its capacity. And it is not my problem if that is his homework question or something. He asked for a solution to this problem, and I gave it.

Comment: The OP has clearly been taught about integer variables because they used them in the posted code. You have absolutely zero evidence they have been taught about anything in the System.Collections.Generic namespace. If he asked you to take his exam for him too would you do it? No. Have some integrity and teach him how to fish, rather than just giving him a fish

Comment: @CaiusJard As I have already said, it does not matter to me what he has been taught or not. This is a solution to this problem that others can also use. At best, he can tell his teacher something like "i looked up what a list is" or something.